# Show that $ {S_n\over 2^.5(logn)} $ converges to 0 almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Suppose ${X_n, n ≥ 1}$ are independent identical random variables with $E(X_n) =0 $ and $E(X^2_n) =1 $
 Show that $$
{S_n\over 2^.5(logn)}
$$ converges to 0 almost surely. where $ S_n =\sum_{i=1}^n X_i $.
I haven't got good idea how to solve it. I used SLLN. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is not true because

$$
\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2}\ln{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{2n\ln{\ln{n}}}}{\sqrt{2}\ln{n}}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln{\ln{n}}}}
$$

and by the LIL

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln{\ln{n}}}}=1 \quad\text{a.s.,}
$$

while the first term in the product converges to $+\infty$.